# how to add button on .php file by editing it

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

```
{!! view_render_event('bagisto.shop.layout.header.account-item.before') !!}
    <login-header></login-header>
{!! view_render_event('bagisto.shop.layout.header.account-item.after') !!}

<script type="text/x-template" id="login-header-template">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div id="account">

            <div class="welcome-content pull-right" @click="togglePopup">
                <i class="material-icons align-vertical-top">perm_identity</i>
                <span class="text-center">
                    @guest('customer')
                        {{ __('velocity::app.header.welcome-message', ['customer_name' => trans('velocity::app.header.guest')]) }}!
                    @endguest

                    @auth('customer')
                        {{ __('velocity::app.header.welcome-message', ['customer_name' => auth()->guard('customer')->user()->first_name]) }}
                    @endauth
                </span>
                <span class="select-icon rango-arrow-down"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="account-modal sensitive-modal hide mt5">
            <!--Content-->
                @guest('customer')
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <!--Header-->
                        <div class="modal-header no-border pb0">
                            <label class="fs18 grey">{{ __('shop::app.header.title') }}</label>

                            <button type="button" class="close disable-box-shadow" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text fs20" @click="togglePopup">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <!--Body-->
                        <div class="pl10 fs14">
                            <p>{{ __('shop::app.header.dropdown-text') }}</p>
                        </div>

                        <!--Footer-->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <a href="{{ route('customer.session.index') }}">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        class="theme-btn fs14 fw6">

                                        {{ __('shop::app.header.sign-in') }}
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <a href="{{ route('customer.register.index') }}">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        class="theme-btn fs14 fw6">
                                        {{ __('shop::app.header.sign-up') }}
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endguest

                @auth('customer')
                    <div class="modal-content customer-options">
                        <div class="customer-session">
                            <label class="">
                                {{ auth()->guard('customer')->user()->first_name }}
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <ul type="none">
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('customer.profile.index') }}" class="unset">{{ __('shop::app.header.profile') }}</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('customer.orders.index') }}" class="unset">{{ __('velocity::app.shop.general.orders') }}</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('customer.wishlist.index') }}" class="unset">{{ __('shop::app.header.wishlist') }}</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('velocity.customer.product.compare') }}" class="unset">{{ __('velocity::app.customer.compare.text') }}</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('customer.session.destroy') }}" class="unset">{{ __('shop::app.header.logout') }}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endauth
            <!--/.Content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">

        Vue.component('login-header', {
            template: '#login-header-template',

            methods: {
                togglePopup: function (event) {
                    let accountModal = this.$el.querySelector('.account-modal');
                    let modal = $('#cart-modal-content')[0];

                    if (modal)
                        modal.classList.add('hide');

                    accountModal.classList.toggle('hide');

                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
            }
        })

    </script>
@endpush
```

I have a php file for creating login page
it look like this [page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXPtH.png)

how to add a new login button like **login with google** by editing in it.

Please be detail while giving your answer, it is very helpful for those who are new in php.

It is better to provide general answers that is helpful for those who are working in other domain related to php.

This code belong to bagisto framework which is base on laravel.Bagisto is greate framework for creating ecommerce sites.

This is the repo of bagisto https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto.git

I am new to stackoverflow so feel free to improve my question for more clarity friends if need.

Comment: There are extensive documentation available from Google. Please follow the link: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web

Answer (score 0):

We have added social login in our master branch, you may take a pull from there. Below is the provided PR link
https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto/pull/3367

PS - as the user asked the questions regarding the platform bagisto that's why I am answering for that purpose.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.